# JButton Value If Else Conditon with JSpinner doesn't work properly

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jspinner

I'm trying to make a timer that has a `jbutton` called `Short Break` and a `jbutton` called `Customize`.

By clicking the default `Short Break` button the time will be set to **`5.00`** minutes.

But the user can customize the time with the help of `JSpinner` by clicking on the `customize` button.
But if the user wants to reduce the short break time by clicking on the `customize` button, then clicking on the `short break` button after customizing will show the customized time.

But after customizing, the customized time is shown, but clicking on the `short break` button without customizing does not show the default value. Means that the `if` condition only work but the `else` condition doesn't.

My JSpinner Code:

```
spinnerShortBreak.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            value2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(spinnerShortBreak.getValue()));
        }
    });
```

The `Short Break` button Code:

```
btnShortBreak.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            timer.stop();
            second = 00;
            minute = 05;
            if (spinnerShortBreak !=null && spinnerShortBreak.getModel().getValue().equals(value2)) {
                lblMinute.setText(String.valueOf(value2));
            }
            else if(spinnerShortBreak == null && spinnerShortBreak.getValue() == null) {                    
                btnStartStop.setText("Start");
                lblMinute.setText("05");
                lblSecond.setText("00");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Seems that every time you change the `JSpinner` value, you update variable `value2` and that's why the `if` statement in your `actionPerformed` method is always true. In other words, method `stateChanged` is always executed before method `actionPerformed`. So whenever `actionPerformed` is executed, the `SpinnerModel` value is always equal to `value2`. I assume this is not what you want. Consider posting a [mcve] so that I may be able to give you a proper answer rather than a guess. Or try running your code with a debugger to verify whether `stateChanged` always executes before `actionPerformed

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution. If i check the value is equal to `0` or greater than `0` the code will work perfectly.

here the button code:

```
btnShortBreak.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            timer.stop();
            if(value2 > 0){
                second = 00;
                lblMinute.setText("0"+String.valueOf(value2));
                btnStartStop.setText("Start");
                lblSecond.setText("00");
            }
            else if(value2 == 0) {
                second = 00;
                minute = 05;
                btnStartStop.setText("Start");
                lblMinute.setText("05");
                lblSecond.setText("00");
            }
        }
    });
```